# iOS JSPatch override delegate method make object not release

Tags: javascript, ios, delegates

I am using JSPatch in iOS, and have overriden a delegate method. But I found the object that calls this delegate method didn't release until after a long time. I'm confused why this is happening.

```
defineClass('OCClassName', {    
    delegateMethod: function(caller) {
        self.ORIGdelegateMethod(caller);
    },
```

The caller will call `delegateMethod`. When this method run, the caller will not release until a long time, even if I have not already used it.

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: i have added code